# Range standardization (0 to 1) in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scale a series between two points in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468280/scale-a-series-between-two-points-in-r)

Does any know of an R function to perform range standardization on a vector? I'm looking to transform variables to a scale between 0 and 1, while retaining rank order and the relative size of separation between values.

Just to be clear, i'm not looking to standardize variables by mean centering and scaling by the SD, as is done in the function scale().

I tried the functions mmnorm() and rangenorm() in the package 'dprep', but these don't seem to do the job.

Comment: Identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468280/scale-a-series-between-two-points-in-r/5468527#5468527

Comment: It is also very much identical to this question on stats.stackexchange: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1112/442

Comment: Don't delete it; just close it.  It's linked to the other question, so it may be useful for people using the search functionality.

Comment: That's called **'scaling'**. Scaling can be by all sorts of denominators, not just the variable's SD; so not just the way the R builtin function 'scale()' does it. Admittedly it would be better if the builtin 'scale()' was parameterized to allow min-max scaling, or other possibilities.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
s = sort(rexp(100))

range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}

range01(s)

  [1] 0.000000000 0.003338782 0.007572326 0.012192201 0.016055006 0.017161145
  [7] 0.019949532 0.023839810 0.024421602 0.027197168 0.029889484 0.033039408
 [13] 0.033783376 0.038051265 0.045183382 0.049560233 0.056941611 0.057552543
 [19] 0.062674982 0.066001242 0.066420884 0.067689067 0.069247825 0.069432174
 [25] 0.070136067 0.076340460 0.078709590 0.080393512 0.085591881 0.087540132
 [31] 0.090517295 0.091026499 0.091251213 0.099218526 0.103236344 0.105724733
 [37] 0.107495340 0.113332392 0.116103438 0.124050331 0.125596034 0.126599323
 [43] 0.127154661 0.133392300 0.134258532 0.138253452 0.141933433 0.146748798
 [49] 0.147490227 0.149960293 0.153126478 0.154275371 0.167701855 0.170160948
 [55] 0.180313542 0.181834891 0.182554291 0.189188137 0.193807559 0.195903010
 [61] 0.208902645 0.211308713 0.232942314 0.236135220 0.251950116 0.260816843
 [67] 0.284090255 0.284150541 0.288498370 0.295515143 0.299408623 0.301264703
 [73] 0.306817872 0.307853369 0.324882091 0.353241217 0.366800517 0.389474449
 [79] 0.398838576 0.404266315 0.408936260 0.409198619 0.415165553 0.433960390
 [85] 0.440690262 0.458692639 0.464027428 0.474214070 0.517224262 0.538532221
 [91] 0.544911543 0.559945121 0.585390414 0.647030109 0.694095422 0.708385079
 [97] 0.736486707 0.787250428 0.870874773 1.000000000
```

Adding `...` will allow you to pass through `na.rm = T` if you want to omit missing values from the calculation (they will still be present in the results):

```
range01 <- function(x, ...){(x - min(x, ...)) / (max(x, ...) - min(x, ...))}
```