# Scaling a column into another column with normalized discrete values

Tags: r, dplyr, normalization, scaling

I've read the previous posts and understand that my question is answered in different ways but I need to verify if I am on the right track please.
I have a column in my data that ranges form 0.00012 to 1452. My goal is to rescale or normalize this column into a factor column ranging from 1 to 20 that are all discrete numbers then round to whole numbers.
I have read this post [Scale a series between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468280/scale-a-series-between-two-points) and also this
[R- Normalizing certain columns from 0 to 1 with values equal to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803509/r-normalizing-certain-columns-from-0-to-1-with-values-equal-to-0) that help but I can't get my final result.
A sample of the data is as follows:

`df_sample <- data.frame(performance_time= c(0.00012,0.12,3.45,12.65,5.8,145,782.45,1452,92.78,101.32))`

Output of interest should be a rescaled column of C ranging from 1 to 20 and all discreet values.
It would be great if I can perform it using dplyr.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Not sure what "numbers that are the closest to their origin with decimals" means. Do you want to rescale between 1 and 20, then round to whole numbers? If so it's `x <- (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)); x <- 1 + 19*x; x <- round(x)`

Comment: @dash2 that's what I meant, sorry about the confusion. Thank you