# Normalize variables from 0 to 1 with different range of variables?

Tags: r, function, normalization

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1),
                 x2=c(1, 10, 5, 8, 3))
```

And I'm trying to normalize both variables between 0 and 1. So 2 in `x1` would be 0.5 and 5 in `x2` would also be 0.5.

I have tried using the following normalization function:

```
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x, na.rm = T))/(max(x, na.rm = T)-min(x, na.rm = T))}
df <- range01(df)
```

But instead it normalizes all variables by range of the entire data frame (1 to 10), giving this:

```
x1          x2
0.0000000   0.0000000           
0.1111111   1.0000000           
0.2222222   0.4444444           
0.1111111   0.7777778           
0.0000000   0.2222222
```

How can I normalize both columns by their individual range? I need a systematic function to do this, since I am working with many variables across many data frames in a for loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scaling r dataframe to 0-1 with NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926022/scaling-r-dataframe-to-0-1-with-na-values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do in one line:

```
sapply(df, function(x) (x - min(x, na.rm = T)) / (max(x, na.rm = T) - min(x, na.rm=T)))

      x1        x2
[1,] 0.0 0.0000000
[2,] 0.5 1.0000000
[3,] 1.0 0.4444444
[4,] 0.5 0.7777778
[5,] 0.0 0.2222222
```

Comment: Or `sapply(df, range01)`. Upvote, but you forgot that the OP seems to have `NA`'s in the data.

Answer (score 3):

With base R:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) {(x - min(x, na.rm = T))/(max(x, na.rm = T) - min(x, na.rm = T))})

      x1        x2
[1,] 0.0 0.0000000
[2,] 0.5 1.0000000
[3,] 1.0 0.4444444
[4,] 0.5 0.7777778
[5,] 0.0 0.2222222
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("x")), 
           funs((. - min(., na.rm = T))/(max(., na.rm = T) - min(., na.rm = T)))) #Applying the function to vars that starts with "x"

   x1        x2
1 0.0 0.0000000
2 0.5 1.0000000
3 1.0 0.4444444
4 0.5 0.7777778
5 0.0 0.2222222
```

Or a different `dplyr` solution, applying the function to all columns:

```
df %>%
 mutate_all(funs((. - min(., na.rm = T))/(max(., na.rm = T) - min(., na.rm = T))))
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) (x - min(x, na.rm = T))/(max(x, na.rm = T) - min(x, na.rm = T)))]

    x1        x2
1: 0.0 0.0000000
2: 0.5 1.0000000
3: 1.0 0.4444444
4: 0.5 0.7777778
5: 0.0 0.2222222
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option based on the scales package

```
library("scales")
df <- data.frame(x1=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1),
         x2=c(1, 10, 5, 8, 3))
sapply(df, rescale)
```

The default option is the 0-1 range but you can also pass other ranges (e.g. 0-100)

```
 sapply(df, rescale, to = c(0, 100))
```