# PCA scaling not applied to individuals?

Tags: r, pca

This issue applies to my own data, but for the sake of reproducability, my issue/question is also present in the FactoExtra vignette, or [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/factoextra/reference/get_pca.html), so I'll use that for the sake of simplicity.

To start, a simple PCA was generated (scale = T) and the coordinate variables from the first 4 axes extracted:

```
head(var$coord) # coordinates of variables
```

> ```
> >                   Dim.1       Dim.2       Dim.3       Dim.4
>
> > Sepal.Length  0.8901688 -0.36082989  0.27565767  0.03760602
>
> > Sepal.Width  -0.4601427 -0.88271627 -0.09361987 -0.01777631
>
> > Petal.Length  0.9915552 -0.02341519 -0.05444699 -0.11534978
>
> > Petal.Width   0.9649790 -0.06399985 -0.24298265  0.07535950
> ```

This was also done for the "individuals." Here is the output:

```
head(ind$coord) # coordinates of individuals
```

> ```
> >       Dim.1      Dim.2       Dim.3        Dim.4
>
> > 1 -2.257141 -0.4784238  0.12727962  0.024087508
>
> > 2 -2.074013  0.6718827  0.23382552  0.102662845
>
> > 3 -2.356335  0.3407664 -0.04405390  0.028282305
>
> 4 -2.291707  0.5953999 -0.09098530 -0.065735340
>
> 5 -2.381863 -0.6446757 -0.01568565 -0.035802870
>
> 6 -2.068701 -1.4842053 -0.02687825  0.006586116
> ```

Since the PCA was generated with `scale=T`, I'm highly confused as to why the individual coordinates are not scaled (-1 to 1?). For instance, "individual 1" has a DIM-1 score of -2.257141, but I have no comparative basis for the variable coordinates which range from -0.46 to 0.991. How can a score of -2.25 be interpreted with a scaled PCA range of -1 to 1?

Am I missing something?
Thanks for your time!

## Updated with all relevant code gaps filled:

```
> data(iris)

> res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)

> ind <- get_pca_ind(res.pca)

> print(ind)

>var <- get_pca_var(res.pca)

> print(var)
```

Comment: @Hack-R I wasn't sure if I should do that since this is either an issue of a bug, or my incorrect interpretation! Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the author of FactoExtra this question. Here was his reply:

> Scale = TRUE will normalize the variables to make them comparable. This is particularly recommended when variables are measured in different scales (e.g: kilograms, kilometers, centimeters, …);(http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/).
>
> In this case, the correlation between a variable and a principal component (PC) is used as the coordinates of the variable on the PC. The representation of variables differs from the plot of the observations: The observations are represented by their projections, but the variables are represented by their correlations.
>
> So, the coordinates of individuals are not expected to be between -1 and 1, even if scale = TRUE.
>
> It’s only possible to interpret the relative position of individuals and variables by creating a biplot as described at: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/.

A biplot isn't idea for me, but I have tried rescale and it works. Also, I suppose I could take an individual and project them into the PCA to see where they fall.

Anyways, that's the end of that. Thanks for your help @Hack-r!

Answer (score 1):

The scaling that is being done when `prcomp(...,scale=T)` is scaling *of the input variables to unit variance*.

I don't think it does anything about  range standardization of the individual co-ordinates, unless perhaps `center = ...` is used. However, it would be easy to do post-hoc (or pre). Here's a related post:

[Range standardization (0 to 1) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665599/range-standardization-0-to-1-in-r)

Comment: Right, but I don't see why the individuals wouldn't be on the same scale. I don't see how I could interpret a PC-1 value of -2.55 when the scale is -1 to 1. However, I just tried the link you posted and gave rescale a shot - it seems like that might work out! Thanks!

Comment: @Eric It sounds like you may be confusing the scaling of the ***variance*** with the range of the values. Nothing that happened in the original code made any attempt to put the ***values*** on a -1 to 1 scale. You scaled the ***variance***.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused about the application of this. For instance, in the original post, how can you make any conclusions about "individual 1?" (PC1: -2.257141 PC2: -0.4784238  PC3: 0.12727962  PC4: 0.024087508) Essentially, I'd like to see "where the individuals are" within the PCA that was generated.