# Why is for-loop not required for to build a function to scale all values in a vector between 0 and 1?

Tags: r, for-loop

I found this previous thread here:

[Range standardization (0 to 1) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665599/range-standardization-0-to-1-in-r)

This leads me to my question: when building a function to perform a calculation across all values
in a vector, my understanding was that this scenario is when the use of `for`-loops would be necessary (because said calculation is being all applied to all vector values). However, apparently that is not the case. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

All of the basic arithmetic operations in R, and most of the basic numerical/mathematical functions, are natively *vectorized*; that is, they operate position-by-position on elements of vectors (or pairs of elements from matched vectors). So for example if you compute

```r
c(1,3,5) + c(2,4,7)
```

You don't need an explicit `for` loop (although there is one in the underlying C code!) to get `c(3,7,12)` as the answer.

In addition, R has *vector recycling* rules; any time you call an operation with two vectors, the shorter automatically gets *recycled* to match the length of the longer one. R doesn't have scalar types, so a single number is stored as a numeric vector of length 1.  So if we compute

```r
(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
```

`max(x)` and `min(x)` are both of length 1, so the denominator is also of length 1. Subtracting `min(x)` from `x`, `min(x)` gets replicated/recycled to a vector the same length as `x`, and then the pairwise subtraction is done. Finally, the numerator (length == `length(x)`) is divided by the denominator (length 1) following similar rules.

In general, exploiting this built-in vectorization in R is **much** faster than writing your own `for`-loop, so it's definitely worth trying to get the hang of when operations can be vectorized.

This kind of vectorization is implemented in many higher-level languages/libraries that are specialized for numerical computation (`pandas` and `numpy` in Python, Matlab, Julia, ...)