# Scatter plot matrix in R: fixed $x$ and $y$ range or eliminating outliers?

Tags: r

I'm writing an evolutionary algorithm with several individuals and generations. In each generation I measure traits (characteristics) of all the individuals. I needed to make scatter plots of these traits for each generation and did so using `pairs()`. The graphic looks amazing but I have the problem that some generations have individuals that are far from the mean and mess up the $x$ and $y$ ranges and make it hard for me to compare generation by generation.

Is there a way to fix these ranges so that scatter plots from different generations have the same ranges? Each trait would need a different range.

An alternative solution to my problem would be to find a way to only plot the points that are within certain distance to the mean, but I don't know how to do these either.

Comment: Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468280/scale-a-series-between-two-points

Comment: That wouldn't work because the extreme values would define the 0 and 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.