# R: scaling integer64 data table columns (containing also NAs) between two values

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have a data table consisting of multiple columns. Column 1:3 are integer64, columns 4:8 are numeric.
I want to scale the integer64 columns (which contain both ingeter64 values and NAs) between 0 and 5, leaving NAs as NAs.

The min value of integer64 columns is 1e+5, while the max is 1e+20.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you give an example? For normal numbers, of course `(x-min(x))/diff(range(x))*5` works. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 re making a good example.

Comment: I have just realized this was a stupid question. Regardeless of the type of data input (numeric or integer64), what I will get from the rescaling is anyway a numeric value. The solution was very easy, I just divided the orinignal value by 1e+10, this return numeric values, which can be then rescaled between 0 and 5 either using Frank suggestion or scale as in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468280/scale-a-series-between-two-points