# Normalization different expected output

Tags: r

I would like to use normalization for 0 until 1 using this function:

```
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
```

if I use it for single case it works fine

However I would like to use it for a whole dataframe in which it find the min and max of all columns and makes the normalization
I used this option:

```
data.frame(apply(df[2:ncol(df)], 2, range01))
```

However it doesn't give the exepected results. Any idea if the apply should be different?

Comment: You are currently applying it in each column separately. To do it on the data frame as a whole, simply do `range01(df[-1])`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/5468280/680068

Comment: Also, `data.frame(apply(...))` is a bad idea, much better is `df[-1] <- range01(df[-1])`.

Comment: Could you post a data sample? In my mind what could be going wrong is that using the apply function would generate a matrix and then you're trying to coerce it to a data frame. But I'm not sure without any sample data.

Comment: It would also be nice to specify how exactly the output is not matching your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below, where you define a custom function `normalize`, i.e.,

```
normalize <- Vectorize(function(v) (v-min(v))/diff(range(v)))
dfout <- data.frame(normalize(df))
```

**Example**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = runif(10,1,5), b = runif(10,2,10))

> df
          a        b
1  2.062035 3.647797
2  2.488496 3.412454
3  3.291413 7.496183
4  4.632831 5.072830
5  1.806728 8.158731
6  4.593559 5.981594
7  4.778701 7.740948
8  3.643191 9.935249
9  3.516456 5.040281
10 1.247145 8.219562
```

and then you will get

```
> dfout
           a          b
1  0.2307452 0.03608002
2  0.3515024 0.00000000
3  0.5788577 0.62607041
4  0.9586953 0.25454974
5  0.1584522 0.72764475
6  0.9475749 0.39387104
7  1.0000000 0.66359501
8  0.6784675 1.00000000
9  0.6425811 0.24955981
10 0.0000000 0.73697057
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option. I always like the `mutate_at` and `mutate_all` functions from `dplyr` to apply functions across different columns.

```
#your function
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}

#some data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = runif(10,1,5), b = runif(10,2,10))


library(dplyr)
mutate_all(df, range01)
#>            a          b
#> 1  0.2307452 0.03608002
#> 2  0.3515024 0.00000000
#> 3  0.5788577 0.62607041
#> 4  0.9586953 0.25454974
#> 5  0.1584522 0.72764475
#> 6  0.9475749 0.39387104
#> 7  1.0000000 0.66359501
#> 8  0.6784675 1.00000000
#> 9  0.6425811 0.24955981
#> 10 0.0000000 0.73697057
```