# rescale the selective range into 0 - 1?

Tags: r, tidyverse, scale, normalization, rescale

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(FC=c(1, 2, 4, 2, 1, -4, -2))
```

And I'm trying to rescale the positive values between 0-1 and negative values also between 0- -1 so the output would be:

```
 FC
0.25
 0.5
   1
 0.5
0.25
  -1
-0.5
```

I have tried "scales" package in r

```
df$FC <- rescale(df$FC, to = c(0, 1))
```

But it is rescaling all values between 0-1.

How can I normalize columns by their individual range?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you need the `range(df$FC)`

Comment: Sure if it can give the desired output. Thank you bro.

Comment: But, it is not giving your expected output though i.e. `rescale(df$FC, to = range(df$FC))` and `rescale(df$FC, to = range(abs(df$FC)))`

Comment: I thinnk the `from` is already doing the `range` and if we specify the `to` as also the range, it returns the input itself

Comment: I don't know much so I can not answer your question now. I need to check it how this rescale and range works.

Comment: Essentially running this on the positive and negative numbers separately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468280/scale-a-series-between-two-points

Comment: @thelatemail I will check and get back to you. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option

```
transform(
    df,
    FC_scaled = FC / abs(ifelse(FC > 0, max(FC), min(FC)))
)
```

which gives

```
  FC FC_scaled
1  1      0.25
2  2      0.50
3  4      1.00
4  2      0.50
5  1      0.25
6 -4     -1.00
7 -2     -0.50
```

Comment: oh wow much needed, it is working as required. Thank your kind help. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

You could just slice your data into positives and negatives and handle each individually.

```
df <- data.frame(FC=c(1, 2, 4, 2, 1, -4, -2))

library(scales)

df[which(df$FC>0),] <- rescale(df[which(df$FC>0),], to=c(.25,1))
df[which(df$FC<0),] <- rescale(df[which(df$FC<0),], to=c(-.5,-1))

df
```

Output:

```
     FC
1  0.25
2  0.50
3  1.00
4  0.50
5  0.25
6 -0.50
7 -1.00
```

Please note however, that I did not specify the range to be between 0 and 1 because that would not get you the output you were looking for. If I did the output would be this:

```
          FC
1  0.0000000
2  0.3333333
3  1.0000000
4  0.3333333
5  0.0000000
6  0.0000000
7 -1.0000000
```

Comment: I will check and get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

We may also use `sign` with similar logic as in @ThomasIsCoding post

```
df$FC_scaled <- with(df, FC/setNames(range(FC),
           c(-1, 1))[as.character(sign(FC))] * sign(FC))
```

-output

```
 df
  FC FC_scaled
1  1      0.25
2  2      0.50
3  4      1.00
4  2      0.50
5  1      0.25
6 -4     -1.00
7 -2     -0.50
```